# Prestashop 1.6 Webservices: how to fetch the products' attachments?

Tags: web-services, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Web+service+reference doesn't list any "attachments" or "product_attachments" etc. resource. Moreover, I have tested to fetch the products thanks to the corresponding resource present in the list, *but* the products don't contain any reference ID to the attachments, nore the attachments object at JSON format.

So how to fetch the products attachments? Is it possible, at least?

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't or at least I could find it.

You can add it by overriding core `Product` class.

1. Add new method

   ```
   public function getWsProductAttachments()
   {
       $result = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_)->executeS(
           'SELECT pa.`id_attachment` AS id, a.file, a.file_name
           FROM `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'product_attachment` pa
           LEFT JOIN `' . _DB_PREFIX_ . 'attachment` a ON (a.id_attachment = pa.id_attachment)
           ' . Shop::addSqlAssociation('attachment', 'a') . '
           WHERE pa.`id_product` = ' . (int) $this->id
       );

       return $result;
   }
   ```
2. Add next element to `$webserviceParameters['associations']` property:

   ```
   'attachments' => array(
               'resource' => 'product',
               'api' => 'products',
               'getter' => 'getWsProductAttachments',
               'fields' => array(
                   'id' => array('required' => true),
                   'file' => array(),
                   'file_name' => array(),
               ),
           ),
   ```

Now your `products/{id}` request will return something like

```
<attachments nodeType="product" api="products">
    <product>
    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
    <file><![CDATA[cc046998a333a9bffaa23ce292f2da43edb37065]]></file>
    <file_name><![CDATA[bbb.yml]]></file_name>
    </product>
    <product>
    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
    <file><![CDATA[b04566afd74cdaa54c921c8907c7efd489a2eec0]]></file>
    <file_name><![CDATA[aaa.csv]]></file_name>
    </product>
</attachments>
```

And you can download attachments like `my.shop/download/cc046998a333a9bffaa23ce292f2da43edb37065`